# Inserting Unicode string without prefix ' N....'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The background of this question is that I have a column with the following definition:

```
FirstName VARCHAR(100).
```

I can insert a THAI/Chinese/European value if I change the column datatype to NVARCHAR and when inserting a value I need to Prefix it with N, as

```
Insert into table ([FirstName]) value(N'THAI/Chinese/European value').
```

Question:

There are a lot of applications that update this particular column and for me to assist this change I need to make a lot of changes to the procedures and various other application level changes. Is there a way I can make a change at the database level where I can accommodate this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make a change at the database level where I can accommodate this change.

I don't believe there is any way to force SQL Server to handle all varchars as unicode nvarchars. They are simply different datatypes.

If you are using literals in your SQL code, you will have to use `N''`. Any columns, parameters, or variables that hold the data will have to be nchar/nvarchar. Your apps will all have to send unicode values to the DB.

I would search for "sql server migrate to unicode" for additional reading before you take this on.

Comment: Tim, So say I change my column datatype to NVARCHAR(100).Should I still use prefix N like INSERT into TABLENAME([FIRSTNAME]) Value(N'ABC') or can I just do INSERT into TABLENAME([FIRSTNAME]) Value('ABC')

Comment: Is there any collation(Column LEVEL) that I need to change to accommodate THAI or Chinese Characters?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @TimLehner that I do not know of a way to force SQL Server to handle all `varchar` columns as `nvarchar` columns, there are a few things that could make *your transition* to Unicode strings in the column easier:

1. To support Unicode values in the column one-off or in an upgrade script, use `ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN FirstName nvarchar(100)`.  (Of course, be sure to update your create script for `[table]` if applicable too - i.e. `CREATE TABLE [table] (FirstName nvarchar(100)...)`.)
2. Use Unicode (i.e. `N'SomeFirstName'`) literals where you expect to insert or set strings with Unicode characters; *but* continue to use non-Unicode (i.e. `'SomeFirstName'`) literals where you do not *in transition*.
3. Work your way up to altering procedures' parameters (i.e. from `varchar` to `nvarchar`) as needed.

Basically, *ideally* you would change the column and everything related to it to support Unicode at once; but you may be able to limit *initial changes* to application(s), procedure(s) etcetera that initially need to leverage the column's underlying Unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a stored procedure for inserts and updates. If then the entire application uses that, you can solely update the stored procedure...

But i guess that would still require an update on all locations, so i guess this is not that much help...